# Using "<" in a Java regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I have a regex for less than symbol:

```
String s="<99";
if(s.matches("[<]*")){
    \\code
}
```

Unfortunately, that is not working for me.  Can anyone explain why this doesn't work?

Comment: have you tried escaping it? `\<`

Comment: Does it not work because it always matches? The star `*` in regex means "repeated 0 or more times".

Comment: no it does'nt go inside the if block

Comment: That's because your string is not a sequence of `<`. there are other characters also. You need to match them too.

Comment: i tried it like this as well if(s.matches("\\[<]*")){} still not working

Comment: Are you perhaps searching for a regex such as `<\s*\d+` (an `<` following any or no space followed by a number?

Comment: < isn't a metacharacter in regex, is it? You should just be able to say `<*`.

Comment: yea it worked but what if i want to have less than and greater than symbol in an or condition in the regex then how to do that??

Comment: @user1767444 `(<|>).*` <-- That

Answer (score 5):

How about

```
if(s.matches("<.*"))
```

the dot will match any character. So this is < followed by any number of any characters.

Answer (score 1):

For this particular String, you can use this regex: -

```
s.matches(".*?<*.*")
```

- If you use [<]*, it will only match strings with 0 or more `<`